# Counting votes between certain dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've done a system for a client where they can nominate colleagues for doing a great job.  Each person has 12 nominations to give annually.

So I've got a database with a table nominations which stores, id, nominator(id), nominated(id), reason and date.

I've also got a table user which stores user data such as, total nominations given, received, id, email etc.

So I'm creating a page from which you can pull reports.

Here you can choose a start date and end date and amount of records you would like.

How would the SQL query look to determine who made the most nominations between the specified dates?

I'm not a SQL guru at all...so any help would be appreciated very much.

After some research I've managed to find out COUNT(*) is the way to go...but don't want to run a query for every user that nominated between the specified dates...and sorting it this way could be a problem.

Please any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

```
select nominator, count(*)
from yourTable
where nominatedDate >= '1 Jan 2013' and nominatedDate <= '31 Jan 2013'
group by nominator
```

When you do aggregation functions (like COUNT. MIN, MAX, AVG) you either need to apply them to every row selected, which will give just one row in the output, or to GROUP BY items you want to make into sub-totals. In this case, for each value of Nominator in the table we get the Nominator value, and the count of rows containing that value.

The Where clause limits the counted rows to those where nominatedDate is in the given range. You can put AND and OR other tests (its already got one and).

Comment: Thanks a lot, how can I order it from most nominations given to least given in timefram?  I'll obviously add a ORDER BY...but not sure by what I should order it?